# Screen blackout when camera launched

Tags: android, tabs, camera, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am doing a qr code scanning when a tab item is clicked in my application. But onclick of the tab, screen blacks out for 3 secs and then the scanning camera starts. Is there a way to avoid this blackout or any related work arounds?

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this,CaptureActivity.class);
    intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    setupTab(getResources().getString(R.string.icon_scan),R.drawable.scan,    0,intent);
```

This is the code for tab setup where Capture activity contains the code for scanning and decoding.

Comment: you need to show some code..also check in ddms ..does it show any exceptions or errors

Comment: there aren't any exceptions or errors in DDMS during this blackout

Comment: did you try it on a real device ..the emulator sometimes is slow in processing all that stuff so it kinda lags...I had a similar problem with a show dialog once but it ran fine on the real device

Comment: i am running the application on honeycomb device. Still the problem persists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right, I believe. The camera driver always takes a second or so to start up, which is the delay in starting the scanning activity. 3 seconds is a long time though -- sounds like a device deficiency.